# How to replace NaNs of a vector to empty cells in matlab

Tags: matlab

I would like to replace NaNs of a  vector with empty cells in matlab.
Any suggestion would be much appreciated.

Comment: in the same array? `find(yourvector==NaN)=[]`? the question is not really clear..

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response.Yes in the same arrays and I want to  keep the same size of vector

Comment: For example A=[1  2 NaN 5 6] I need to have B=[1 2 emptycell 5 6]

Comment: then this won't work. see the answer by @Suever

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In an array you *cannot* replace a value with an empty value (`[]`). If you try to, this will simply remove that element therefore changing the size. This is because you are replacing a value of length = 1 with a value (`[]`) of length = 0.

```
a = [1, NaN, 2];

%// Replace all NaNs with []
a(isnan(a)) = [];

%// 1  2
```

This is likely why there are NaNs there in the first place. NaNs are a good placeholder within a numeric array.

If you do actually want empty values instead of NaN values, you would need to convert it to a cell array.

```
a = [1 NaN 2];

%// Convert to cell
acell = num2cell(a);

%// Replace all NaNs with []
acell(isnan(a)) = {[]};

%//  [1]    []    [2]
```

I would highly discourage you from doing this as cell array are significantly slower than a numeric array and whatever processing you are doing can likely be easily adapted to handle (or ignore) the NaN entries.

Comment: `acell(isnan(a)) = {[]}`

Comment: Thanks jucestain  and dear Suever. I need to convert the data from matlab to spss and fill the emty cells when I convert to spss emty cells change to cells with zero values !

Comment: @Ava If you wanted, you could maybe replace the NaN with a value that you know means nothing: `-999` or something.